# Как сделать чтобы текст не растягивал табличный div, который установлен в процентах?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать чтобы текст не растягивал табличный div, который установлен в процентах?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>None</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css">



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

   
    <style>

        .ceneral_conteiner {
            background-color: grey;
        }

        .conteiner_right{
          display: table-cell;
          width: 0;
        }

        .conteiner_left{
          display: table-cell;
          width: 100%;
          background: red;
        }


      
        .con_item_left {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30px;
            height: 90px;
            background: green;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .con_item_right {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 98%;
          height: 100px;
          vertical-align: top;
          background-color: blue;
        }
</style>

</head>


<body>

    
    <div class="ceneral_conteiner">
        <div class="conteiner_right">
            <div class="con_item_left"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="conteiner_left">
            <div class="con_item_right">ееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееее</div>
        </div>
    </div>
















</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно добавить `word-break: break-all;` в `.con_item_right{}`

```css
.ceneral_conteiner {
  background-color: grey;
}

.conteiner_right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
}

.conteiner_left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.con_item_left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 90px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.con_item_right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 98%;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: blue;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="ceneral_conteiner">
  <div class="conteiner_right">
    <div class="con_item_left"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="conteiner_left">
    <div class="con_item_right">ееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееее</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Во! Ппц как я это пропустил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <title>None</title>
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css">
    
    
    
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    
     <style>
    
      .ceneral_conteiner {
       display: table;
       background-color: grey;
       table-layout: fixed;
      }
    
      .conteiner_right{
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: top;
       width: 2%;
      }
    
      .conteiner_left{
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: top;
       width: 98%;
       background: red;
      }
    
    
    
      .con_item_left {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 100%;
       background: green;
       word-break: break-all;
      }
    
      .con_item_right {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 100%;
       background-color: blue;
       word-break: break-all;
      }
     </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="ceneral_conteiner">
     <div class="conteiner_right">
      <div class="con_item_left"></div>
     </div>
    
     <div class="conteiner_left">
      <div class="con_item_right">ееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееее</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Внимательно посмотрите CSS очень много ошибок.

Comment: С акцентируйте пожалуйста на ошибках. Интересно посмотреть.

Comment: @Shnur Скажите пожалуйста, в чем состоят ошибки?

Comment: @Shnur Да, кстати, вы привели код  другой функциональности. У вас два блока указаны в процентах по ширине, а у меня один фиксированной ширины, а второй в процентах.

Comment: display: inline-block;  vertical-align: top; вместе работать не будут vertical-align работает только с таблицами (td или display: table-cell). Если вы используете таблицу, то нужно задавать 98% ячейке, а не элементу в ячейке, это разные вещи. Вам же нужно для DIV табличного типа. Далее если уже делаете табличные DIV соблюдайте правила таблиц table > td хотя бы так, т.к. некоторые возможности вырубите на корню.

Comment: @Shnur 1. display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;  - проверьте, у меня почему то все работает. Даже в примере который я привел.  2.`Если вы используете таблицу, то нужно задавать 98% ячейке, а не элементу в ячейке, это разные вещи. ` - вы не внимательно ознакомились с вопросом, и дали не верный ответ, и не верный комментарий к ответу, который противоречит функциональности начального алгоритма. Мне нужно именно задавать 98% элементу а не ячейки. `table > td`С дивам это не оязательно делать.